# Error using "Click In" Keyword - Robot Framework with Sikuli Lib

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, robotframework, sikuli

I have the following problem using Robot Framework with Sikuli Lib:

When using the keyword "Click In" I get an error.
I don't know what it could be.

Could they help?

> **Error:**

org.sikuli.script.SikuliXception: image to search (22, 23) is larger than image to search in (310, 18)

> **Test**

```
Click In    image_full.png    icon_from_image.png
```

Can anybody help me?

The objective is, through an image of a region, to click on an icon from another image (icon, which exists in the image of the region)

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Error says your reference image is bigger than where the you want to look for it to be present. Eg. Your reference pic is 23pixels ans app is only 18. How about trying to remove the extra 4 pixels ?

Comment: rasjani, thanks for the return. Bug i tried to remove the extra 4 pixels (1, 2, 3 and 4 pixels) and received the below error: com.github.rainmanwy.robotframework.sikulilib.exceptions.TimeoutException: Timeout happened, could not find P(image_full.png) S: 0.699999988079071

Comment: Could you help me?

Comment: I'm receiving this error too: org.sikuli.script.FindFailed: image_full.png: (27x25) in M[292,59 302x25]@S(0) S:1,00 C:443,71 [140 msec]

Comment: I have only briefly skimmed thru sikuli so i cant really help out but if i understand the error message, it says "The image you have in image_full.png cannot be seen in the desktop" ..